# How to trace back methods to their classes then their packages? Java Syntax

Tags: java, syntax, methods

I have been recently trying to utilize the Java API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). I was wondering how I can locate the "page.drawRect" method. Is the "drawRect" method apart of the "page" class ? I'm not sure if that's how the syntax works, or if I'm making sense. All I want is an explanation of 
"page.drawRect" and maybe some tips on how to use the API documentation. Nothing is wrong with the actual code I posted. Thank you :)

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class HopeThisWorks extends JApplet
{

    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        page.drawRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
        page.drawRect(60, 80, 225, 30);
        page.drawOval(75, 65, 20, 20);
        page.drawLine(35, 60, 100, 120);

        page.drawString ("\"Don't try to be like Jackie. There is only one Jackie. " + 
        "Study computers instead.\"", 110, 70);
        page.drawString ("-Jackie Chan",130, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple

- *packages* are just named containers of class definitions and they don't contain code or methods, just .java files
- methods can reside only in classes

In your example you are talking about the `Graphic` class, `page` is indeed a reference to a Graphic instance. So you should look for class [`java.awt.Graphic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).

Whenever you import a package you don't need to specify the full qualified name of a class contained inside that package, that's why you can use plainly `Graphic page` instead that `java.awt.Graphic page` but this is just a shorthand to make everything less verbose (and sometimes more ambigue).

Comment: Wow I appreciate the quick and helpful responses. Thank you :) !

Answer (score 1):

`drawRect` a method in the `Graphics` class. Have a look at [Graphics.drawRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

`page` here is the variable instance name for the applet `Graphics` object.

For more see:

[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good enough. Adding a small note.

Use an IDE like [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-inline-documentation.html)/Netbeans/Eclipse.  Most of these tools has ability to take appropriate definition, show quick documentation etc.

[Pragmatic Programmer Tip- Use one editor well](http://pragmatictips.com/22)

Comment: I should look into learning more about my IDE (Eclipse). BTW that site has a lot of good advice. I bookmarked it ! Thanks :)

Comment: @ V1rtualcurry : 'That site' is actually has tips from the book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pragmatic_Programmer - IMHO, a must read for all programmers.

Answer (score 1):

> maybe some tips on how to use the API documentation

If you're using Eclipse,

1. Right-click on your project and select <kbd>Properties</kbd>
2. Select <kbd>Javadoc Location</kbd>
3. Enter "`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`" in the <kbd>Javadoc location path</kbd> textfield
4. Tap <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now you will be able to step into the source code, or simply hover over `drawRect` and read the associated documentation.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding you completely so I can remove my answer if need be...

Comment: WOW, thank you very much ! It works when I mouse over it. I should definitely learn more about my IDE ! Thank you !

Comment: @V1rtualCurry, No problem, glad I could help. If you want to step into the source code, select the method you want to step into and press **F3**.